Bowing during Shmonei Esrei - why only sometimes
Why don’t we bow every time we say “Barach Ata” during Shmonei Esrei? Are you allowed to if you wanted to? Is there a specific reason why we only bow at specific brachas?
Thanks

https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.34a.14

It is a subject of Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 113:1 and Mishna Berurah there. Technically, one can bow at the end of each blessing and in the middle. At the beginning of a blessings it is inappropriate. The reason, so that not to uproot takanat chachamim which will make it appear that each and every praying person is stringent in accordance with his liking, and suspect to being arrogant, who want to show they are stricter than the rest of the tzibur.

Thank you, this answers the first and second question, my only remaining question is why was the Takana for specifically these brachot?

@ShtikaK'hodaah Mishna Berurah there has more discussion and gives further points to look in a few places. I do not have an easy access to these right now. I will be happy if you find it out yourself and write the answer. It's a very good question.

But by not bowing at the beginning of each blessing, one could possibly conclude it reveals a different kind of arrogance, thus potentially creating the same issue.

@EndAntisemiticHate the hachamim defined arrogance differently. We have a tradition. We certainty live in a different culture.
